# A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution installing Glide in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle

I'm reading a documents regarding the new glide on how to install on my app, Its quite difficult now since they update the new api and document unlike before and following there instruction, but why I'm getting this error:

```
A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
```

I tried already so many ways to debug it. but my issue was not still resolve.

Here is my `build.grade:app`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.8.1")

    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have forgot to add dependancy

try this

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
  kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
}
```

also add in your this inside of your project level `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
    }
```

Comment: Yes2, I forgot to implements its dependencies, but I will accept this as a good answer.